# How to copy directories via ssh

Tags: ssh, directory, cp

I am connected with `ssh` and I want to copy a directory from my *local* to our *remote* server; how can I do that?
I have read several post using `scp` but that doesn't worked for me. Some posts suggested using `rsync` but in my case I just want to copy one directory.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you want to copy a directory from machine a to b while logged into a:

```
scp -r /path/to/directory user@machine_b_ipaddress:/path/to/destination
```

If you want to copy a directory from machine a to b while logged into b:

```
scp -r user@machine_a_ipaddress:/path/to/directory /path/to/destination
```

Comment: I think more intuitive answer would be "from machine b to a while logged into a" anybody can swap a in the head, but would indicate source/destination much better, unless I'm crazy :)

Comment: @PawelCioch While I definitely agree with you, it's not difficult to comprehend. I did write this answer almost 3 years ago, and I wasn't very good with English :)

Comment: Well several years on, 2020, and I thank you for your answer, found it easy to read with no problems. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Well, now the question is "how to be logged into b".

Answer (score 10):

You can use `cpio` or `tar` to create an archive as a stream on standard output, pipe that to ssh and extract the stream on the remote host. For example, using tar:

```
tar cf - dir | ssh remotehost 'tar xf -'
```

To extract the archive in a different directory on the remote host, use

```
tar cf - dir | ssh remotehost 'tar xfC - /path/on/remote'
```

If your `tar` supports the `C` option or:

```
tar cf - dir | ssh remotehost '
  cd /path/on/remote && tar xf -'
```

if not.

If on a low bandwidth connection, you may want to compress the stream:

```
tar cf - dir | gzip -3 | ssh remotehost '
  cd /path/on/remote && gunzip | tar xf -'
```

(replace `gzip`/`gunzip` with your stream compressor of choice, `lzop`/`lzop -d` may be a better choice if you find that CPU is the bottleneck).

Answer (score 2):

Think this might work for you:

```
scp file user@host:/location_to_save_file
```

`scp` - secure copy
 - the file(s) you want to scp to remote node
 - the user who has permissions to scp file, i.e sysadmin, etc
`@` - user and host separator
host - the node you are scp the file(s)
`:/location_to_save_file` - absolute path to save the file

Comment: With the addition that you need to add the `-r` flag if you want to copy a directory instead of a file, like @hrk is asking.