# error when using scp -r to copy files from my local host to remote host

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to transfer a directory from my local host to a remote server.

I am using a Mac.

i keep getting this message

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/Users/seeker/Documents/devfolder/Laravel/Dating/baseLaravelDating/dating/’: No such file or directory
```

I followed the instruction in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374823/how-to-copy-directories-via-ssh)

i.e I first logged into the remote server via **SSH** and from the root of server I ran the following;

```
scp -r /Users/seeker/Documents/devfolder/Laravel/Dating/baseLaravelDating/dating   root@192.123.135.237:/home/elite/elite
```

I know that the location of the local files is correct because i ran the command:

> PWD

The files i am trying to transfer is located in a directory called **dating**.

Comment: You should run `scp` on your local machine to copy your local files. Also, are you sure you want to login as `root`?

Comment: hi @panki. thanks for replying. what is wrong with using root

Comment: See this detailed explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it/82639#82639